# openpyxl: Linter insists that cell is merged

Tags: python, openpyxl

So I've got an excerpt from one of my classes:

```py
def write_wb(self,filename: str):
    """Write the workbook to filename. """
    #This lets us defer excel ops until the end
    headers = ["Path","File","Type","Description","Link"]
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    wb.active.append(headers)
    for elem in self._internal_array:
        wb.active.append([elem.path,
                          elem.name,
                          elem.type.name,
                          ''])
        linkcell = wb.active.cell(row=wb.active.max_row,column=5)
        linkcell.value = "1" #This line has the error
        linkcell.style = "Hyperlink"
        linkcell.font  = Font(underline="single")
```

My linter (pylance) keeps complaining of the following:

> Cannot assign member "value" for type "MergedCell"
> Expression of type "Literal['1']" cannot be assigned to member "value" of class "MergedCell"
> Type cannot be assigned to type

Given that I created the workbook in line 5, I can make a compile-time guarantee that that cell will *never* be a MergedCell or a ReadOnlyCell. What's going on and how do I make my linter happy?

Comment: Commenting out the line appending `elem.path` etc results in no error. Can you provide an example of these?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. When I comment out that line, the error remains. Again, this is a pylance linting error, not a runtime error. Check that you have at least basic typechecking on.

Comment: Ah apologies, I was able to replicate. Good solution

Comment: The way you look up the linkcell looks a little weird but this looks like a problem with the linter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to include your customized cell in the call to `append`. This code works:

```py
for elem in self._internal_array:
    linkcell = openpyxl.cell.Cell(wb.active,
               value=f'=HYPERLINK("{elem.link}")' if elem.link else '') 
    linkcell.style = "Hyperlink"
    wb.active.append([elem.path,
                      elem.name,
                      elem.type.name,
                      '',
                      linkcell])
```

The error comes from the fact that Pylance can't be sure that calls to `wb.active.cell` won't return an invalid cell, so it applies all the restrictions it can for future code.